# Game center invitation failing on 2nd generation ipod touch

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, game-center

I am working on a multiplayer game with connections via Game Center and GKMatch.  I have three devices -- a 4th generation iPod touch, a 2nd generation iPod touch, and an iPad 2.  Connecting the two newer devices works just fine.  But if I try to use the older device to connect one of the newer ones, Apple's default invitation says "want to play (null)?" instead of "want to play ([name of my game])?".  And the newer device never gets a message that the older one has invited it.

The older device is running iOS 4.2.1.  The newer ones are running iOS 4.3.3.

Inviting the older device with a newer one also fails.  The invitation looks correct, but the older device never receives it.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Hay, I am also facing the same problem. you got any solution about this?